# Удаление заданного элемента до определенного места

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется список [5,2,1,1,1,2,1,5], требуется в нём удалить 1 до индекса 4 включительно. Как это сделать по простому? То есть на выходе должно быть [5,2,2,1,5]. Хотелось бы увидеть наиболее короткий код, так как такую операцию со списком буду проделывать многократно.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
l = [5,2,1,1,1,2,1,5]
for i in l[1:4]:
    l.remove(i)
```

Comment: ваш код выдает `[5, 1, 2, 1, 5]` хотя должен `[5, 2, 2, 1, 5]`

Comment: Имелось ввиду l.remove(1)

Comment: Greed Wizard, спасибо!

Comment: Greed Wizard, не, этот код мне не подходит, так как он опирается на то, что известно количество удаляемых элементов. Скажем на списке l = [5,2,2,1,5] он падает, так как говорит, что единиц больше нет. Разумеется я не могу сказать сколько их будет, если не посчитаю. А в общем случае задача раз в 100 сложнее.

Comment: Можно, конечно, на соответствующих местах, то есть когда `i` добегает до `[5,2,1,1,1]` запускать предварительно написанную функцию, которая принимает список `l` и индекс `i`, запускает цикл от `0` до `idx` по подсчёту `l[i]` в какой-нибудь `count` и возвращает этот `count`. Выглядит просто слишком замороченно как-то. А затем уже писать `for j in l[i-count:i]`

Answer (score 1):

```
def squeezeones(lst, endpos):
    delcnt = 0
    for i in range(0, min(endpos + 1, len(lst))):
        if lst[i] == 1:
            delcnt += 1
        elif delcnt:
            lst[i - delcnt] = lst[i]
    return lst[:endpos-delcnt+1] + lst[endpos + 1:]

print(squeezeones([5,2,1,1,1,2,1,5],4))
>>>[5, 2, 2, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Почему тут цикл до длины массива, если можно до индекса удаления?

Comment: Потому что здесь конец переписывается на освободившееся место (я планировал укоротить имеющийся список, не создавая нового). Это в принципе можно сделать отдельным циклом или собрать результат из сжатого куска + остаток за тем индексом.

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял:

```
input_ = [5,2,1,1,1,2,1,5]
output = input_[0:2] + input_[5: len(input_)]
print(output) # [5, 2, 2, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Такой вариант не подойдет. Мне надо выдергивать наборы, которые в сумме дают 10. Вариант Greed Wizard самое то, если он действительно правильно работает. Суть в чем, мы добегаем до [5,2,1,1,1] забираем список, удаляем единицы. Бежим по новой до [5,2,2,1], забираем список, удаляем единицы, бежим по новой [5,2,2,5] получаем больше 10, удаляем двойки, и опять пробегаем по [5,5], забрали, удалили, список пустой, функция закрылась.

Comment: SKIP, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо работать с общим случаем, когда список, удаляемый элемент и область поиска может быть любой, то лучше всего создать метод с данным функционалом:

```py
def delall (lst, x, end):
  while lst[:end].count (x) > 0:
    end = end - 1
    lst.remove (x)
```

*Принцип работы: пока в срезе поиск есть искомый элемент, то удаляется первое вхождение.*

Далее надо будет просто вызывать этот метод с нужными входными параметрами:

```py
lst = [5,2,1,1,1,2,1,5]
print (lst) # [5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5]
delall (lst, 1, 5)
print (lst) # [5, 2, 2, 1, 5]
```

Стоит обратить внимание на то, что если вам надо искать до индекса `x` включительно, то в метод надо передавать `x+1`, т.к. оператор `[:end]` возвращает срез не включая индекс `end`.